# Javascript hashing algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, string-hashing

I'm trying to learn how to do some basic hashing in Javascript and I've come across the following algorithm:

```
var hash = 0;
for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    char = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
    hash = hash & hash;
}
```

I don't really understand how it works and I was hoping you could help me out. In particular I don't understand `(hash<<5)-hash` and `hash = hash & hash`. Thank you for your replies.

**Note:** For anyone looking for the source, it's an implementation of Java’s String.hashCode():
 http://werxltd.com/wp/2010/05/13/javascript-implementation-of-javas-string-hashcode-method

Comment: Where did you find that code? I don't think it's very good as an example.  In particular, the `hash = hash & hash` step looks superfluous. It may be there to keep the value in the integer range, I suppose.

Comment: I don't remember exactly. I was searching on Google and this came up. I recently though about it and since I didn't really understood how it worked, I posted it here.

Comment: Can you put up a better example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step

```
  hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
```

is effectively:

```
  hash = ((hash * 32) - hash) + char;
```

Then,

```
  hash = hash & hash;
```

will only change the value if the number has overflowed the integer range (32 bits, or maybe 31). (I wouldn't do it that way but it's a matter of style.)

In that code, the variables "i" and "char" should be declared:

```
var hash = 0, i, char;
```

Comment: On this example if you have a hash equal to 0010 and shift left 5 bits 0100 0000.

Comment: @user3376708 right, so `0010` is 2 and `0100 0000` is 64, which is `2 * 32`.

Answer (score 2):

<< and & are bitwise operations. One is shifting bits and the other is anding them.

`0010 << 2` becomes `1000` because everything is shifted to the left.

`0101 & 1110` becomes `0100` because the result is 1 whenever both values have 1's for that particular bit.

@Pointy's answer explains what the `hash = hash & hash` (& the same value) accomplishes, I wasn't sure what it did.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Does it always just automatically convert the hash to a binary number or is there some place in the code that you have to tell it to convert to binary?

Comment: Every type of data is already represented as bits. If you try to use a bitwise operator on a non Number type JavaScipt will attempt to convert it to a number first.

Answer (score 2):

A common technique for hashing is to start with 0. Then you multiply the existing hash value by a prime number, and finally add the new element to it.

In this case:

```
((hash << 5) - hash)
```

is effectively "hash * 31". Apply the left shift operator, `<<`, 5 times is like multiplying the number by 2, 5 times. Or, multiplying it by 2^5, which is 32. Then they subtract once, giving 31.

The `hash & hash` is effectively a "do nothing" operation, performing a logical AND (`&`) on a number with itself returns the same number, it doesn't "do anything", but it may be used to coerce the number and make sure it remains an integer. There's likely some JS machinations going on with the representation of the number and that's what the second line is for.

If this was just raw C, it would simply be `hash = hash * 31 + char`.

Answer (score 0):

`hash << 5` is bitshifting the value of hash to the "left" 5 places.  This is equivalent to `hash * 32`.  For a hash-generation algorithm, it's easier to think of it in terms of moving the bits.

`hash = hash & hash` looks like a mistake.  It "ands" the value of hash with itself and assigns it back to itself.  Anding the value with itself results in the original value, so it's a form of nop.

Answer (score 0):

The << represents the left shift operation. This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the left, for example:

```
var num = 2; // in binary 10
var shift = 2 << 2;  //shift is 8, in binary 1000
```

The & operator represents an AND logical operation, for example:

```
var num1 = 6; // in binary 110
var num2 = 7; // in binary 111
var result = num1 & num2; // result is 6, in binary 110
```

for a complete reference on bitwise operators take a look on the [Mozilla javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).